# Angular 4 pagination in API

Tags: angular, pagination

I'm calling an API endpoint that uses pagination in the header. I want to make use of that, so I need to take two steps:

- I need to parse the HTTP `Link` header.
- I should implement pagination in Angular 4.

So currently, I have this service built:

```
getBooks() {
    return this.http
      .get(`${BaseService.baseUrl}/books`)
      .map(response => <Book[]> response.json());
}
```

Now I need to parse the headers from the response, but I'm not sure how to? I'm also not sure how I should build the pagination in my component.

Who could set me up with some help, please?

Comment: I'll briefly comment on the headers part. The response object contains a headers property. See the documentation here:  https://angular.io/api/http/Response

Comment: How would I extract it? Currently I call the getBooks() service method in my component, so I already lost the headers thanks to the .map() method, right?

Comment: Sort of, yes. Within the map method you could map the response object to anything you want, including a JSON object of your own design that includes the headers (along with the Book[] you are already returning). Then the calling code would have access to both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll need to grab the headers from the response.

```
getBooks() {
return this.http
  .get(`${BaseService.baseUrl}/books`)
  .map(response => {
    let headers = response.headers;
    let pagination = headers.get('pagination-header'); // get specific header
    // do something with header
    return {
      headers: headers,
      res: <Book[]>response.json()
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Now I need another piece of advice, if you don't mind. When I return that object, how do I use it in my component if I use the subscribe() method on the return value in the service?

Comment: so you would just subscribe to this observable. the value returned from the success callback of the subscribe will be what you returned from the map function. so now you can use the headers & json response as needed.

Comment: So the first parameter in the subscribe method will be the object with headers and response? Awesome, thanks!